# Google Map Marker Clickable Area in Flutter

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, polyline, google-maps-flutter

Currently, I am working on a taxi application using Flutter. It has a feature to see road conditions and open road cameras. And, I am using polylines for road conditions and markers for opening camera. It's working fine.

The only the problem, I have is related to the Google Map's default marker. Actually, the clickable area differs in Android and iOS. In Android, the area is bigger than the icon size and in iOS, the area is smaller than icon size.

That results, in iOS as, when I click on the edges of marker, it shows the road conditions. On the other hand, in Android, it mostly opens the road camera.

I tried to add custom marker as well. Though, it doesn't resolve the issue.

Any suggestions please.

Thank You.

Comment: There's currently a feature request on Google's Public Issue Tracker that is related to your question. Here's the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823783. I don't think issue has been resolved yet but you can keep yourself updated by `starring` it.

Comment: Thank You @Yrll This is helpful. I will keep track of it. By any means, do you know how can I calculate the marker tap on the map, if I have to do manual calculations?